# Hbase-Spark :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to get data from hbase database (1.2.5) using Spark 2.0.2 with the code in this page : 
https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/JavaHBaseBulkGetExample.java

But I get this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/Logging  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   com.cloudera.spark.hbase.JavaHBaseContext.(JavaHBaseContext.scala:23)
>     at org.hipi.examples.Test.main(Test.java:71)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ... 22 more

I have seen on the internet that Logging class exist only in spark 1.5.2 and lower versions.

Is there is any solution to make that work even with Spark 2.0.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few BUGs related with this:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13928
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-16428